# First build with AndroidStudio failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to android programming and I'd like to use Android Studio for the start. I downloaded and installed AndroidStudio 0.8.0 on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I also set up java properly.
When I create a new project (as told by http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) it looks like it will try to build the sample files. But then I always get this error:

```
/home/daniel/AndroidStudioProjects/Heimweg/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png


Error:Error: Cannot run program "/home/daniel/android/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
```

> /home/daniel/AndroidStudioProjects/Heimweg/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/daniel/android/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory

How can I deal with this error? When I try to run the app it says »ADB not responding. You can wait more, or kill "adb" process manually and click "Restart"«

Comment: :( bummer android studio.  You'll get it.

Answer (score 18):

The Android tools need 32-bit compatibility libraries installed.   I had the exact same problem, and this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 \
lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1
```

Then restart Android Studio.

Comment: That helped :) now I can run the emulator. But I think I should stick to eclipse for now :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the SDK doesn't have all of the components installed!

To remedy this, in Android Studio go to **Tools**->**Android**->**Android SDK Manager**

I would install the Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-Tools, and the Android 4.4 files (and the others as far back as you plan on developing for)

I hope this helps!
Here's some reference with pictures if you need further assistance: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

EDIT:
I apologize! I should have read your error more carefully. It seems that android-4.4W refers to **Android Wear**.

Make sure when you are creating your project that you do not have Android Wear selected under the SDK selection screen (As shown below)

[image: Select project compatibility]

Alternatively you can also open up the **Android SDK Manager** again and install the Wear SDK.
In the SDK Manager it is under **Android 4.4W (API 20)**, install the **SDK Manager** and the two **System Images**

Comment: I tried this but only the error messages changed a little bit.
It's still saying that it cannot find `…/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/aap`
I simply tried to work with Eclipse but there it says that it cannot find `sdk/platform-tools/adb`

Comment: Hey! I edited my post with what I think is a solution. Let me know!

Comment: I don't get it why it's not working. The Wear option is not ticked when I create a new project. I tried multiple Phone and Tablet SDKs but I get this error every time.

Comment: Did you try installing the Wear SDK? If all else fails, I would just uninstall Android Studio and try with a fresh install. The IDE is still buggy.